# How to to produce XML output?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

Is it possible to put a Python output into an XML?

The code I have so far is:

```
with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as StationLog:
    for line in StationLog:
        header = line.split('=')[0]
        if line.split('=')[0].strip() == 'name':
            name = line.split('=')[1].strip().lower()
            print name
        elif line.split('=')[0].strip() == 'siteIP':
            siteIP = line.split('=')[1].strip().rstrip('"').lstrip('"')
            print siteIP
        elif line.split('=')[0].strip() == 'id':
            id = line.split('=')[1].strip()
            print id

The ouput is:
abcd
192.168.1.1
123
```

My desired input is:

```
<Station>
    <name>abcd</name>
    <siteIP>192.168.1.1</siteIP>
    <id>123</id>
</Station>
```

Comment: @KevinW. this isn't a dup.  This is essentially a basic printing question.

Comment: Do you want it to be in an `XML` file or in ? XML` format?